# Firefox WebExtension CSP issue in popup

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to build a browser extension on firefox that supports multiple languages.

I have decided to use `handlebars.js` as a templating engine. But I can't get it work in the browser popup. (I haven't tested it on content script so I'm not sure if it'd even work on content script)

I wanted it to show a sign in button if the user has not pressed sign in on the extension.

When I use the debugger in firefox, it returns this error

`Error: call to Function() blocked by CSP`

I have tried loading it on chrome and it seems to work perfectly fine though.

My manifest.json

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Foo",
  "version": "0.1",

  "description": "",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/blue_z-48.png"
  },
  "background":{
    "scripts":[
      "browser-polyfill.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions":["<all_urls>","tabs"],
  "browser_action":{
    "default_icon":{
      "48":"icons/blue_z-48.png"
    },
    "default_title":"Foo",
    "default_popup":"popup/landing.html"
  },
  "content_scripts":[

  ],
  "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'",
  "web_accessible_resources":[
    "overlay/footer.html"
  ]

}
```

The js part that parses template:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#main-template").html());
var data = {isLoggedin: false};

$("#popup-content").html(template(data));
```

The popup/landing.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css">
    <script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header container">
      <img src="img/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="popup-content">
      <script id="main-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="wrapper">
          {{#unless isLoggedin}}
          <img src="img/sign_in.png"> <span>Sign In</span>
          {{/if}}
        </div>
      </script>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].